# Lista de funciones en Haskell

Tags: funciones, haskell

¿Cómo puedo definir una lista cuyos elementos sean funciones?
¿Cuál sería el tipo a definir si tengo un tipo de datos?:

```
data Usuario = UnUsuario String [**--que tipo pondria aca--**] deriving Show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tipo para una función simple sería `a -> b`, con `a` como tipo de datos del dominio de la función, y `b` como tipo de datos de la imagen. Tu definición quedaría así:

```
data Usuario a b = Usuario String [a -> b] deriving Show
```

El problema con esta definición está en que las funciones no son instancias de `Show` y te dará error ([aquí la explicación](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions)). Puedes usar como alternativa la definición de instancia de `Text.Show.Functions`:

```
Prelude> import Text.Show.Functions
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> data Usuario a b = Usuario String [a -> b] deriving Show
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> let x = Usuario "Hola" [\x -> True, \x -> False]
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> x
Usuario "Hola" [<function>,<function>]
```